# How to keep KEYS secure in fully offline app?

Tags: android, android-keystore, android-security, android-securityexception

I have fully offline app which keeps few KEYS required to achieve functionalities. I am using proguard to secure my app from reverse engineering but afaik it’s not 100% possible to keep app away from reverse engineering.

Also, KEYS are defined as STRING which are immutable. Hence, I think though I use proguard which eventually end up by not obfuscating KEYS.

My question is,

> How to keep KEYS secure in my app also my app requirement is fixed &
>   want to preserve KEYS in-app only?

Comment: "Securing keys" is too broad of a definition. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are the keys required when the app is offline? Do you have user authentication mechanism in place?

Comment: What are you using the KEYS for? The right solution depends on your actual use-case.

Comment: You can consider KEYS as some sort of required dataset for app working/functionality

Comment: I am also searching for the same solution but i am not getting proper way yet

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way possible would be to depend upon some sort of user input (password?) and then derive an key from that input and encrypt/decrypt your keys with that key.

This implies that your application will not work until the user starts it up for the first time (so that she can input the key/password), this might be a problem if the application should be running in the background.

An alternative would be to use the Android KeyStore to encrypt/decrypt your key -- with that you would move your trust from the user to the used device.